# What does STATUS:CLIENT HOLD mean in a domain record?

Tags: domain-name, whois

A site I was once responsible for has disappeared off the interwebs - its [WHOIS record](http://www.whois.net/whois/oxygen-online.org) includes the somewhat mysterious line `STATUS:CLIENT HOLD`.

Is that why the site is no longer accessible (it still seems to have nameservers associated with it as I'd expect)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it means service for the domain has been suspended, possibly due to legal actions (spam complaints etc.). Contact of the domain registrar by the owner is necessary.

The name servers you see in WHOIS are not active - they are jsut there because if the status changes back... they get put in again.

Answer (score 1):

It means the domain is no longer available in the zone file.  Some domain registrars use this to allow you a grace period in which to renew the domain again.

Comment: This was exactly what had happened in my case. Thanks.